# How can I trigger a click on an element inside a child component (that I don't have access to)?

Tags: reactjs

I have installed `react-file-base64` into my React JS project and have implemented it like so:

```
import FileBase64 from 'react-file-base64';
import FileUpload from '../../forms/FileUpload'

...

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <FileUpload buttonText='Upload New Image'>
                <FileBase64
                    multiple={ false }
                    onDone={ this.changeProfileImage }
                />
            </FileUpload>
        )
    }
}
```

The code is obviously condensed for brevity.

As you can see, I've wrapped the `FileBase64` component inside a custom `FileUpload` component - to do the old JS/CSS trick of hiding the file upload and triggering it via a different button press.

Given that I *do not* have direct access to edit the `FileBase64` component, since it's been installed by NPM (and will possibly be updated by it in the future), and given that it is *not* a direct input element but rather a custom component that *renders* one - how can I trigger a click on the input element rendered by the `FileBase64` component, from inside my `FileUpload` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

**Reconsider using react-file-base64**

This is a pretty minor NPM module, so ask yourself: is it worth using a few dozen lines of someone else's code instead of writing the functionality myself? Open source is amazing and leveraging other people's work can be a lifesaver, but learn to recognize when to lean on it and when not to.

**Fork react-file-base64**

Fork the original project and add whatever functionality you need to meet your requirements. Ideally do it in a well-written, well-documented way so that you can later open a pull request and contribute back to the project in a meaningful way.

**Hack it a bit**

It's good to stay inside of React as much as possible, but there are ways around it. You can, for example, still select DOM elements using plain old JavaScript. Remember that stuff? ;P

This would probably work fine - wrap the `<FileBase64 />` component in a `<div>` that you can use to select any nested child `<input>` elements.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...
    onBtnClick() {
        this.inputWrapper.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].click();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <FileUpload buttonText='Upload New Image' callback={this.onBtnClick} >
                <div ref={(el) => this.inputWrapper = el} >
                    <FileBase64
                        multiple={ false }
                        onDone={ this.changeProfileImage }
                    />
                </div>
            </FileUpload>
        )
    }
}
```

I dunno how exactly you're handling `<FileUpload />` click callbacks but you get the idea. After a component renders, its DOM elements are laid bare for you to access. The trick is figuring out how to select those elements in the first place, and being careful that you don't break React in the process. But selecting an element and triggering a "click" event is pretty benign.

Comment: Well said, and on reflection I agree completely with the first two methods (doing it myself, or forking it). I believe the approach I will take is to do the first for now, but hopefully find the time to fork and PR later.

Answer (score -1):

There are several triggers for this component that maybe suits your needs. Some of them are:

1. **beforeUpload**: Triggered before uploading. return true to continue or false to stop uploading.
2. **doUpload**: Triggered after the request is sent(xhr send | form submit).
3. **onabort**:riggered after you aborting a xhr.
4. **uploadSuccess**: Callback when upload succeed (according to the AJAX simply).

If you see the [plugin documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fileupload#life-circle-functions) you can be how they work in detail, as well as more different events to interact with your input element inside your FileUpload component.

Comment: This is not the package mentioned in the post.

Comment: You're right, sorry, i read it bad. Then, the solution should be as simple as wrapper your component into a div, and triggering the `onClick` over this div surrounding the input, as your correct answer propose (I'm totally agree with @jered).

Changing the plugin for another one with more options it should be also an option, once you know you can't trigger something as simple as triggering clicks in input.